# Cannot using where in eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, orm, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I'm using Eloquent ORM in Laravel. There is 2 model, User and Trans. User hasMany Trans, and Trans belongsTo User. The problem is when I'm using query where, it doesn't work.

I tried using `->get()` in the last code, it still doesn't work. I tried using `->all()` in the last code it still doesn't work. I tried whereIn, it still doesn't work.

**User Model**

```php
public function trans()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Trans', 'user_id');
}
```

**Trans Model**

```php
public function user ()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
}
```

**Controller**

```php
$trans = Auth::user()->trans->where('date', $date);
```

I want the output is based on query where the date is based on user input, when I delete `->where` , it works and the output like this.

```php
Collection {#797 ▼
  #items: array:13 [▼
    0 => Trans {#783 ▶}
    1 => Trans {#784 ▶}
    2 => Trans {#785 ▶}
    3 => Trans {#786 ▶}
  ]
}
```

Comment: add `user` and `trans` model in question

Comment: used like that `Auth::user()->trans()->where('date', $date);` add `()` after trans

Comment: when i add () it give me weird array :
HasMany {#803 ▼
  #foreignKey: "transactions.user_id"
  #localKey: "id"
  #query: Builder {#802 ▼
    #query: Builder {#801 ▶}
    #model: Transaction {#799 ▶}
    #eagerLoad: []
    #localMacros: []
    #onDelete: null
    #passthru: array:13 [▶]
    #scopes: []
    #removedScopes: []
  }
  #parent: User {#533 ▶}
  #related: Transaction {#799 ▶}
}

Comment: `Auth::user()->trans()->where('date', $date)->get();` and add get() method to get row  data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change like that

```
Auth::user()->trans->where('date', $date);
```

to

```
Auth::user()->trans()->where('date', $date)->get();
```

> note : if you want  to get only **property** then u get property without
>   `pointer` but if you want to used another **method** then must used(add)
>   pointer(->).